# Circular dependency between declaration of struct and function pointer

Tags: c

I have a struct which has a function pointer as a member variable. The function pointer takes a pointer to the struct as one of its parameters.

By looking at solutions posted on here for such circular dependencies I used a forward declaration to be able to compile.

I still have the problem of not being able to initialize the struct. Posted below is the code and the output.

edit: My earlier MVCE didn't reproduce the problem correctly. I can get this to compile by naming the struct instead of just having a struct alias. Not exactly sure why though.

```
#include "stdio.h"

//Forward declaration
struct data;

typedef int(*funcPtr) (struct data* a);

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    funcPtr foo;
}data;

int foo(data* pData)
{
    return 0;
}

static data testData[] = {{1,1,foo}, {0,2,foo},};

int main()
{
    printf("Just trying to compile this program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Error output --

```
compileError.c:20:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
static data testData[] = {{1,1,foo}, {0,2,foo},};
^
compileError.c:20:1: warning: (near initialization for \u2018testData[0].foo\u2019) [enabled by default]
compileError.c:20:1: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
compileError.c:20:1: warning: (near initialization for \u2018testData[1].foo\u2019) [enabled by default
```

Comment: Side note: It doesn't show in your example code, but your struct isn't `struct data`. It is an unnamed struct type-aliassed to `data`.

Comment: This actually solved the problem I had in my original code. This MVCE code just had a typo which led to other answers. Thank you!

Comment: Your `typedef struct { … } data;` defines an alias `data` for an untagged structure type.  That type is unrelated to the `struct data` you mentioned earlier.  You need `typedef struct data { … } data;` to get the code to compile.  As amended, this is a duplicate of quite a lot of other questions.  Understanding `struct tag { … }` vs `typedef struct { … } tag` seems to be a fairly common problem.

Answer (score 2):

Function `foo` is incompatible with `funcPtr` - it returns an `int`, not a `void`.

Also, your variable is declared as an array, but you initialize it with a single value - remove the `[]`.

Comment: You can have arrays with one element, but you should fully brace your initializer: `data testData[] = { { 1, 1, foo }, };`.  This may be a side-effect of converting the real program into an MCVE.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - It seems to me an array was not intentionally used here.

Comment: Yeah I should have probably used multiple values. My real program uses an array.

Comment: @coder_mario: ideally, you would have indicated that you intended an array by using the extra level of braces, or a comment such as `/* ... */` after the elements you provided. You did a good job on minimization; almost too good.

Comment: Thanks, though this MVCE kinda induced its own bug which didn't let me totally reproduce the issue I had. The comment on the question actually led me to the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You define an array of struct data but initialize it with just one element. If this was unintentional, remove '[]':

```
data testData = {1,1,foo};
```

If an array is needed, initialize with a fully-braced array initializer:

```
data testData[] = { {1,1,foo} };
```

Also, check your member function signature. The declaration and the implementation should both return either `void` or `int`.